# How to add tensorflow math function at the end of Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to add simple tensorflow math function to the end of Keras model, but it is not working. Here is my ridiculous but minimal working code with native Keras Add() function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as ss

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Add
import tensorflow as tf

kernel_size = 64
epochs = 1000

## Data generation for training

x_train = np.random.randn(1024, 512)

t = np.linspace(0, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], endpoint=False)
sine = np.sin(2*np.pi*t/32)
cosine = np.cos(2*np.pi*t/32)

x_I = np.multiply(x_train, cosine)
x_Q = np.multiply(x_train, sine)

b_I = ss.tukey(kernel_size)
b_Q = ss.tukey(kernel_size)

x_I_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_I, x_I_i, mode='valid') for x_I_i in x_I])
x_Q_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_Q, x_Q_i, mode='valid') for x_Q_i in x_Q])

y_train = x_Q_filt + x_I_filt

x_I = np.expand_dims(x_I, axis=2)
x_Q = np.expand_dims(x_Q, axis=2)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=2)

## Keras model

input_I = Input(shape=(x_I.shape[1], 1))
input_Q = Input(shape=(x_Q.shape[1], 1))

conv_I_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_I)
conv_Q_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_Q)

out_I_Q = Add()([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D]) 
# out_I_Q = tf.math.add(conv_I_1D, conv_I_1D)

model_1D = Model([input_I, input_Q], out_I_Q)

model_1D.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error') 
history_1D = model_1D.fit([x_I, x_Q], y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)
```

and after 40 epochs I'm getting almost perfect initial filter kernel:

```
plt.semilogy(history_1D.history['loss'])
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But if I replace Keras `Add()` function with tensorflow equivalent add function: `out_I_Q = tf.math.add(conv_I_1D, conv_I_1D)` I will get this sad loss graph:
[image]
I think that tensorflow math function is not a part of Keras model in this configuration. Changing optimizer type won't help at all. I'm using tensorflow 2.0 and Keras 2.2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [tf.keras.layers.Lambda](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda?version=stable) `layer` combining with `tf.math.add()` as follows:

```
def add_func(inputs):
    return tf.math.add(inputs[0], inputs[1])

out_I_Q = Lambda(add_func)([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D])
```

or

```
out_I_Q = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.add(x[0], x[1]))([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D])
```

**From the documentation:**

> The Lambda layer exists so that arbitrary TensorFlow functions can be
>   used when constructing Sequential and Functional API models.

**Full example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as ss

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Add, Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

kernel_size = 64
epochs = 100

## Data generation for training

x_train = np.random.randn(1024, 512)

t = np.linspace(0, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], endpoint=False)
sine = np.sin(2*np.pi*t/32)
cosine = np.cos(2*np.pi*t/32)

x_I = np.multiply(x_train, cosine)
x_Q = np.multiply(x_train, sine)

b_I = ss.tukey(kernel_size)
b_Q = ss.tukey(kernel_size)

x_I_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_I, x_I_i, mode='valid') for x_I_i in x_I])
x_Q_filt = np.array([np.convolve(b_Q, x_Q_i, mode='valid') for x_Q_i in x_Q])

y_train = x_Q_filt + x_I_filt

x_I = np.expand_dims(x_I, axis=2)
x_Q = np.expand_dims(x_Q, axis=2)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=2)

## Keras model

input_I = Input(shape=(x_I.shape[1], 1))
input_Q = Input(shape=(x_Q.shape[1], 1))

conv_I_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_I)
conv_Q_1D = Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=None, padding='valid', use_bias=False)(input_Q)

out_I_Q = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.add(x[0], x[1]))([conv_I_1D, conv_Q_1D])

model_1D = Model([input_I, input_Q], out_I_Q)

model_1D.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error') 
history_1D = model_1D.fit([x_I, x_Q], y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)

plt.semilogy(history_1D.history['loss'])
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.show()
```

**Out:**

[image]